# How to browse image form HTML and store that image in database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I was making an application which requires to browse image from storage and store it in database.Also i want to show that image when i can select the specific field from database
is it possible to store images using HTML\Javascript & nodejs

i created one file tag like

it displays one text box with one browse button..after seleting the image the path displayed one that text box, Now i want to store that image into MS-SQL SERVER 2008(Enterprise Edition) database.

is it possible..
please help on this topic..

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    Service_name
    
    
    
    Icon
    
    
    
    
    ADD

{{ statusMessage }}

Comment: you don't provide enough details, you cannot save to database from the client, if this is your question. You will have to write a server-side JS (or any language) app in order to save yuour files to server's filesystem / database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right, you should first upload the image, for example into '/img' directory. After that you can save full path of image in your database.

How to upload image ([link](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/file-uploads-using-node-js/))

```
/*Define dependencies.*/

var express=require("express");
var multer  = require('multer');
var app=express();
var done=false;

/*Configure the multer.*/

app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/',
 rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
    return filename+Date.now();
  },
onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
  console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
},
onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
  console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
  done=true;
}
}));

/*Handling routes.*/

app.get('/',function(req,res){
      res.sendfile("index.html");
});

app.post('/api/photo',function(req,res){
  if(done==true){
    console.log(req.files);
    res.end("File uploaded.");
  }
});

/*Run the server.*/
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

[Good article](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/mihail_mateev/archive/2014/07/24/dealing-with-node-js-and-microsoft-sql-server-part-2.aspx) how to use SQL Server

Comment: sir currently i am working on IONIC framework would you please suggest me the soluation for ionic